# У меня есть движущийся объект (синий прямоугольник). Как сделать так, чтобы при перемещении он был позади изображения, а не над ним?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Steam Dry")

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
bgu = bg.get_rect()
win.blit(bg, bgu)

x = 50
y = 425
width = 40
height = 60
speed = 10

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - 5:
        x += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 5:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height - 15:
        y += speed

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255), (x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: А где в коде использование `bg`? Инициализацию вижу, а использования нет

Comment: Я совсем чайник в этом вопросе. Можете поподробнее, пожалуйста, объяснить. Я думал, чтоб картинка как фон была больше ничего не нужно.

Comment: @ФарходФайзуллаев, аналогия: захотели наклеить фотообои комнате, купили в магазине, занесли в комнату, положили на стол. Это еще не означает, что обои сами наклеились на стену в комнате.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. код читается сверху вниз, то и команды для рисования спрайтов надо ставить в таком же порядке. То есть т.к. win.blit() был дан раньше, то отрисовываться он будет раньше чем pygame.draw.rect(). Что бы квадрат отрисовывался раньше, надо команду для отрисовки дать раньше, т.е. просто написать выше чем win.blit(). Вопрос глупый и не стоит вопросов на форуме, лучше повнимательней почитать туторы, книги и справки.